# как создать 3 рандомных не повторяющихся объекта из списка в unity

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, unity3d

Сначала я создал список, который фильтрует объекты.

Чтобы было понятнее, опишу что делает игрок.
Игрок подходит к стойке с книгой. Камера приближается к столу(сделано), и на нем спустя n секунд появляются персонажи из списка, в количестве 3х штук. На каждого из персонажей можно нажать, и тогда появится его биография. После этого, можно убить одного из персонажей. Тогда все 3 удаляются и создаются 3 новых персонажа. Но не создаются те, которые уже были на столе.

```
public void characterFilter()
{
    List<CharactersDie> FilteredData = new List<CharactersDie> ();
    foreach (CharactersDie C in characters) {
        // если объект еще не создавался, то это значение равно 0
        // если создавался, то оно равно 1
        if (C.characterReads == 0) 
            FilteredData.Add (C);
    }
Как из этого списка мне создать 3 рандомных и не повторяющихся объекта?
```

Если поможет, вот полный код

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class LevelManagerScript: MonoBehaviour {

    public UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson.FirstPersonController controller;
    private Books playerReadings;
    private RayCastScript rayCast;
    public GameObject openBook;
    private OpenBook openBooks;
    private CharactersDie[] characters;
    public GameObject deathBookCamera;
    public GameObject characterControll;
    public float loadDelay;

    // Use this for initialization

    void Awake() {
      controller = FindObjectOfType<FirstPersonController>();
      playerReadings = FindObjectOfType<Books>();
      rayCast = FindObjectOfType<RayCastScript>();
      Cursor.visible = false;
      characters = FindObjectsOfType<CharactersDie>();
      //openBook = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("OpenBook");
    }

    void Start() {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
      //if (playerReadings.playerReading) {
      //        Cursor.visible = true;
      //} else
      //    Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    public void reading() {
      controller.enabled = false;
      rayCast.enabled = false;
      Cursor.visible = true;
    }

    public void StopReading() {
      openBooks = FindObjectOfType<OpenBook>();
      rayCast.enabled = true;
      //openBook.TextCanvas.SetActive(false);
      openBooks.OpenBookTextCanvas.SetActive(false);
      openBooks.oneText.SetActive(false);
      openBooks.twoText.SetActive(false);
      openBooks.threeText.SetActive(false);
      openBooks.fourText.SetActive(false);
      playerReadings.playerReading = false;
      controller.enabled = true;
      Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    public void characterFilter() {
      List <CharactersDie> FilteredData = new List<CharactersDie>();
      foreach(CharactersDie C in characters) {
        if (C.characterReads == 0)
          FilteredData.Add(C);
      }

      foreach(CharactersDie C in FilteredData) {
        int prefabIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, C); // это не работает
        Instantiate(FilteredData[prefabIndex]);
      }
    }

    public void deathBookCameraActivate() {
      characterControll.SetActive(false);
      deathBookCamera.SetActive(true);
      Cursor.visible = true;
    }

    public void deathBookCameraDisActivate() {
      characterControll.SetActive(true);
      deathBookCamera.SetActive(false);
      Cursor.visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: А `// это не работает` что значит? не работает метод? или не работает так, как вы ожидаете?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: @dreenline на всякий случай добавил даже способ с LINQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых - когда вы делаете `Range(0, C);` вы пытаетесь сделать рандомные числа в диапазоне от 0 до объекта типа `CharactersDie`. А `Range` принимает в качестве параметров два числа. То есть вообще должна была быть ошибка и никакой компиляции в принципе. Как это не показывало ошибку - мне непонятно.

Во-вторых для генерации рандомных и уникальных элементов, скорее всего надо завести еще один лист, который будет хранить генерируемые значения.
Например:

```
List<int> randomList = new List<int>();

for ( ; randomList.Count < 3; ) {                
    var random = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, FilteredData.Count);
    if (!randomList.Contains(random)) {
        randomList.Add(random);          
        Instantiate(FilteredData[random]);          
    }
}
randomList.Clear();
```

Вот как выглядит это просто на C#: http://ideone.com/dhBT3J

Что тут происходит?

Организуется цикл до тех пор, пока в листе рандомов не накопится 3 объекта. Как уникальные туда попадут? Все просто: в цикле мы говорим "эй, рандомлист, а содержишь ли ты (Contains) уже сгенерированное число (random)? Нет? Ну тогда добавь в меня и заодно можешь инстаинциировать. А если содержишь, тогда иди на новый круг!" По окончании цикла лист очистить. На всякий случай.

В-третьих: уверен, что вместо двух циклов можно сделать все покороче с использованием [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb397676.aspx). но это вы можете сами попробовать сделать, почитав об этом языке.

---

Вот примерно что с LINQ можно сделать (на вашем примере):

```
public void characterFilter() {
    var filteredData = charactersDie.Where(item => item.characterReads == 1).ToList();
    var numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, filteredData.Count).OrderBy(n => n * n * (new Random()).Next()).Take(3);

    // Инстанциировать рандомные объекты
    foreach (var number in numbers) {
        Instantiate(filteredData[number]);
    }
}
```

Как пример: http://ideone.com/QviKXq

Answer (score 1):

Если список небольшой, можно создать еще два списка:
В первый кладете изначальную копию оригинального и циклом по рандому с уменьшением максимального значения вытаскиваете элемент во второй список. Получите неупорядоченный изначальный список из которого и будете выдергивать по 3 объекта.

```
List<object> Original = new List<object>(10); //как то его заполнили
List<object> OriginalCopy = Original.ToList(); //ну или как нибудь по другому скопировать
List<object> RandomList = new List<object>();

int count = OriginalCopy.Count;
int maxRange = count;
for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
{
    //честно не помню, выдает рандом ошибку если min-max одинаковые или нет,
    //если нет, тогда цикл до count прогоняете, а 2 последние строчки не нужны.
    int index = UnityEngine.Random.RandomRange(0, maxRange--); 
    RandomList.Add(OriginalCopy[index]);
    OriginalCopy.RemoveAt(index);
}
RandomList.Add(OriginalCopy[0]);
OriginalCopy.Clear();
```

Затем, если будут нужны повторные циклы, можно OriginalCopy присвоить использованный RandomList, и прогонять уже смешанный список.