# Как исключить генерацию нескольких предметов в одном месте?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Делаю игру, игрок собирает предметы которые рандомно появляются в разных точках заданных в массиве, но при генерации предметов некоторые попадают в одно и тоже место больше 1 раза.

Как исправить этот момент, что бы в одной точке смог генерироваться только 1 объект а другие уже исходя из пустых точек?

```
public Transform[] spawnPoints;  
public GameObject[] enemyPrefabs; 
public int amountEnemies = 20;  
//public List <Transform> spawnPoint;
private int i;

void Start()
{
    Spawn();
}

public void Spawn()
{
    for (i = 0; i < amountEnemies; i++) {


        GameObject obj = enemyPrefabs[Random.Range(0, enemyPrefabs.Length)]; 
        Transform pos = spawnPoints[Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length)];  

        Instantiate(obj, pos.position, pos.rotation);

        }
}}
```

Comment: проверяй наличие в этом месте объекта

Comment: судя из твоего кода получается так, что у тебя всегда `spawnPoints.Length` равен `amountEnemies`.  Иначе просто невозможно представить как сгенерировать, например, 50 монстров на 10 строго заданных точках, причем без повторений)) ..... так что в некоторых случаях генерация в одной и той же точке вполне норма.........вот если бы были заданы границы генерации по координатам - может было бы проще

Comment: пока могу поделиться ссылкой на ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/533168/191482 ..... но в данном случае нужно знать более детально что тут творится)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский тут необходимо что бы из 14 точек, в них рандомно появилось 6 объектов, именно по этому нужно исключить повторение

Comment: это легко сделать за счет доп. переменной в виде списка (лучше вместо массива), который будет копией `spawnPoints` и в цикле после каждой генерации будет вырезать из себя уже использованный индекс.   Однако, всё же, мне интересно, что будет если количество монстров будет превышать количество `spawnPoints`? Какова ожидаемая логика? Аналогично `enemyPrefabs`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский у меня заранее определенно количество spawnpoints оно меньше чем количество генерируемых предметов

Comment: @nika.brown09 это понятно. просто надо всегда думать наперёд. и в если представить, что будет так, как я спрашиваю - будет печально. В данном случае разные подходы будут выглядеть некими костылями но....Я тебе могу предложить теоретически безболезненный вариант: **1 шаг —** создаешь метод `static void Shuffle<T>(T[] array)` (скорее всего надо сделать отдельный класс Helper, чтобы не захламлять основной скрипт), который будет тасовать (перемешивать) элементы массива по методу Фишера–Йетса.

Comment: Ознакомится как он работает можно тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/644925/191482 (хоть и на javascript) или тут https://www.dotnetperls.com/fisher-yates-shuffle, а также почитать в инете что это. Реализация очень простая.. В общем метод, который тасует твой массив с любым типом данных. Далее **2 шаг —** в методе `Start` ты просто заранее применяешь перемешивание к своим массивам, а в методе `Spawn` просто вытаскиваешь их поочереди, т.к. они уже будут перемешаны

Comment: ...тестовая запись...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вынесу-ка я свои комментарии в ответ, пожалуй.

В вашем случае, раз вам всё равно, что в будущем количество монстров может превышать количество `spawnPoints` и что может поломаться логика и  аналогично с  `enemyPrefabs`, то...

Предлагаю теоретически безболезненный вариант:

**1 шаг —** создаешь метод `static void Shuffle<T>(T[] array)` в каком-нибудь дополнительном классе `Helper` (чтобы не захламлять основные рабочие), в котором будут размещаться разные общие  методы-помощники для игры.

Метод `Shuffle` будет тасовать (перемешивать) элементы массива любого типа по методу **[Фишера–Йетса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0)** (а можно и другим методом). 
Ознакомится как он работает можно, например, **[тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/644925/191482)** (хоть и на javascript), а также почитать в интернете что это. Реализация очень простая..

Далее...

**2 шаг —** в методе `Start` ты просто заранее применяешь тот самый метод для  перемешивания к своим массивам, а в методе `Spawn` просто вытаскиваешь их по очереди, так как они уже будут перемешаны.

В целом выглядит это так:

Класс `Helper` и метод `Shuffle`:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Helper: MonoBehaviour {

    public static void Shuffle <T> (T[] ts) {
        var length = ts.Length;
        var last = length - 1;

        for (var i = 0; i < last; ++i) {
            var r = Random.Range(i, length);
            var tmp = ts[i];
            ts[i] = ts[r];
            ts[r] = tmp;    
        }
    }
}
```

Основной класс:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MyTestClass: MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform[] spawnPoints;
    public GameObject[] enemyPrefabs;
    public int amountEnemies = 20;
    private int i;

    void Start() {
        Helper.Shuffle(spawnPoints);
        Helper.Shuffle(enemyPrefabs);

        Spawn();
    }

    public void Spawn() {
        for (i = 0; i < amountEnemies; i++) {
            GameObject obj = enemyPrefabs[i];
            Transform pos = spawnPoints[i];
            Instantiate(obj, pos.position, pos.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**P.S.** Класс `Helper`  прикреплять к чему-нибудь на сцене не обязательно. Так как не обязательно делать каждый класс унаследованным от `MonoBehaviour`, но при этом хочется иметь доступ к методу, то достаточно того, что метод `Shuffle` статический. К нему в любом случае будет доступ через `Helper.Shuffle()`

Comment: Господа минусовальщики, хотя бы объясните что не так. Может мне исправить что надо? Непонятно просто, что с ответом не так

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю от себя - сам недавно столкнулся с похожей проблемой. Суть в следующем: я создал массив для оси X, Y и Z и заполняю его так, как мне нужно - указываю нужное расстояние между объектами и все такое. Затем перемешиваю значения по X в случайном порядки (или по любой другой оси) и при этом значения из других массивов перемешиваются в точно таком же порядке. В результате у меня универсальный алгоритм случайного появления любого количества объектов. Единственная проблема - объекты не могут появиться, например, змейкой, а появляются строго сеткой. Но мне подходит такое решение, да и модернизировать вроде можно... Вот код:

```
public class ObjectSpawnerScript : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject myObject;

public int maxObjects = 10; // задавайте столько, сколько хотите
public int curObjects = 0;

public int positionX = -6;// быдлокод. Можно обойтись
public int positionY = -2;// быдлокод. Можно обойтись
public int positionZ = 1;// быдлокод. Можно обойтись
public int space = 3;

public List<int> spawnPosX = new List<int> ();
public List<int> spawnPosY = new List<int> ();
public List<int> spawnPosZ = new List<int> ();

void FillPosition(){
        spawnPosX.Add (positionX);
        spawnPosY.Add (positionY);
        spawnPosZ.Add (positionZ);
        //ChangePosition ();
    }

    void ChangePosition(){
        if (positionX <= 0 && positionY < 6) {
            FillPosition ();
            positionX = positionX + space;
        }

        else if (positionX > 0) {
            positionX = -6;
            positionY = positionY + space;
            ChangePosition();
        }
        else if (positionY >= 6) {
            positionY = -1;
            positionZ++;
            ChangePosition ();
        }
    }
void ShufflePosition(){
        // перетасовывает значения
        ShuffleScript.Shuffle (spawnPosX, spawnPosY, spawnPosZ); // описан в другом классе
}
void Start () {
for (int i = curObjects; i < maxObjects; i++) {
            ChangePosition();
        }
        ShufflePosition ();
for (int i = curObjects; i < maxObjects; i++) {

            Instantiate (myObject, new Vector3 (spawnPosX[i]
                , spawnPosY[i]
                , spawnPosZ[i]), Quaternion.identity);
            curObjects++;
        }
}
```

Упс, не скопировался код другого класса:

```
public static class ShuffleScript {
//private static System.Random rng = new System.Random(); // для случайной сортировки массивов
private static System.Random rng = new System.Random((int) DateTime.Now.Ticks & 0x0000FFFF); // для случайной сортировки массивов

// сортирует массив в случайном порядке, следующие массивы сортируются так же, как и первый
public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list, IList<T> list2, IList<T> list3)  
{  
    int n = list.Count;  
    while (n > 1) {  
        n--;  
        int k = rng.Next(n + 1);  
        T value = list[k];  
        list[k] = list[n];  
        list[n] = value;

        T value2 = list2[k];  
        list2[k] = list2[n];  
        list2[n] = value2;

        T value3 = list3[k];  
        list3[k] = list3[n];  
        list3[n] = value3;
    }  
}
}
```

Копировал свой код и не адаптировал его под ваш, но разобраться вроде не сложно.
Еще обновление: здесь объект спавнится так (не учитывая перетасовку) - сначала появляются 3 объекта, потом 3 объекта над первыми тремя, затем три объекта над вторыми тремя (выглядит как цифры на клавиатуре телефона - от 1 до 9), потом все то же самое происходит на `positionZ++`